Why is angular momentum in a 2-body system conserved if the points about which we take them are moving?
Consider a two-body problem. I understand that if the angular momentum of either body is taken about their barycenter, then its angular momentum is conserved. I also understand that if the angular momentum of either body is taken about the other, then its angular momentum is also conserved. I can follow the derivation for both of these results, however it's contradictory with what my intuition tells me.
If the angular momentum of a body is taken about a stationary point, then as long as there is no net torques on said body, then its angular momentum is conserved.
If the angular momentum of a body is taken about a moving point, then not only does the net torque on said body have to be 0, but the motion of the point must be parallel to the body.
In the case of the 2 body problem, either scenario involves taking the angular momentum about a moving point (barycenter or orbiting planet). And the velocity of the moving point and the bodies definitely aren't parallel. This doesn't meet both conditions I said above, which means then that the angular momentum must be changing.
So why do I get a contradiction here? What's wrong with my thinking?

You are considering the two-body problem. You can decompose it into the motion of the barycentre and the equivalent one-body relative motion. In the equivalent one-body relative motion, the two bodies are thus moving in a frame of reference whereby the centre of mass is kept fixed.
The barycentre is going to obey Newton's 1st Law. This is a straight line uniform motion. No matter which pivot you want to choose, moving or not, the angular motion of this two-body system about said pivot, is going to decompose exactly into the "barycentre position from pivot" cross product by total linear momentum, added to the angular momentum about barycentre. The latter term is coming from the equivalent one-body relative motion, i.e. is the same for all frames of reference, because it is defined and measured from the barycentre frame of reference.
$$\vec{\vec L}=\vec r\times\vec P+\vec{\vec{I_\text{CoM}}}\,\vec\omega$$
Since $\vec P$ conservation leads to $\vec r\times\vec P$ conservation, and $I_\text{CoM}\,\omega$ is separately conserved, thus $L$ is also conserved.

I don't think this explains OP's scenario. You say, "No matter which pivot you want to choose, moving or not ... $\vec P$ conservation leads to $\vec r\times\vec P$ conservation", where $\vec r$ is the "barycentre position from pivot". The change of $\vec r$ over time is due to motion of both barycenter and pivot. It's true that the barycenter's motion is parallel to $\vec P$, but the pivot's motion is not necessarily parallel to $\vec P$!

Could you explain the difference between the 1 body and 2 body problem? I'm not sure what the difference is.

@nanoman I was trying very much to be clear earlier, that the pivot can have any uniform linear motion. i.e. satisfy being a Galilean frame of reference. As long as that is true, then it doesn't matter, and the conservation will follow.

@AeroMain27 There is no much to it? It is just a routinely proved thing that a two-body problem can be decomposed into centre-of-mass motion and a relative one-body problem. The search term is "reduced mass". The real thing is still two bodies in motion, but the one-body is obviously much simpler to solve.

@naturallyInconsistent "can have any uniform linear motion" -- even if that were true, OP asked about the case where the pivot is one of the orbiting bodies, i.e., not in uniform linear motion. What do you think of my answer?

@nanoman You are correct that I did not explicitly talk about that situation. However, I chose not to talk about it because a) the OP said that he had already proved that case to get the same numerical value, and b) the reduction of two-body problem to one-body problem automatically also heavily hints (and actually can be used to prove) that this has to work. And so I thought it was a trivial consequence and did not explicitly mention it. As for your own answer, I really dislike treatments that invoke fictitious forces, so I did not want to entertain it. But your argument seems ok.

If I have two equal masses $m$ in a circular orbit a point at $v$ and radius $R$, you'd be inclined to say each has an:
$$ L = mvR $$
The force on each is:
$$ F = \frac{mv^2} R $$
The torque each applies on the other is:
$$ \vec\tau = \vec R \times \vec F = 0 $$
so
$$ \frac{dL}{dt}=0 $$
Now if I move the origin $O$ over a distance $D$ (much greater than $R$ for clarity).
Now when I calculate angular momentum about $O$..I'm not in the mood for trig, so I'll look at the case when $O, m_1, m_2$ are in syzygy:
$$ L_1 = mv(D-R) $$
$$ L_2 = mv(D+R) $$
so, clearly their angular momentum is changing as they orbit.
If look at the case where the are equidistant from $O$, the force they apply on each other is perpendicular to their distance from $O$ (to 1st order), and the torque they apply to each other is:
$$ \tau \approx FD = mv^2D/R $$
You can work out the torque and angular momentum for a whole orbit, and see Newton still stands at all times.
tl;dr $\vec L$ and $\tau$ are pseudo vectors (and I don't mean axial vectors--they are that, too), but by pseudo vector I mean they depend on the definition of the origin, which proper euclidean vectors do not.

I haven't thought about this deeply but my thesis advisor did back in the day.  Sometimes, when trying to be precise about angular momentum, he would add the clarification "a fixed point instantaneously coincident with [the point you are summing angular momentum around]."  I never fully understood the technicality but the upshot was that on a practical level, angular momentum balance works around moving points. BUT the correct way to think about it was that you are doing AMB about a series of points that are instantaneously coincident with the point of interest (a hinge or a COM, for example).

So if I’m understanding this correctly, you’re saying to treat the  moving point (other planet or barycenter) as really a series of different stationary points?

Yes, basically.  And if the point is not at a COM, you have to account for the COM acceleration with an $\bf r \times m a$ term.


if the angular momentum of either body is taken about the other, then its angular momentum is also conserved.

Understanding this requires clarifying exactly what is meant by "taken about the other" and "conserved".
The standard definition of angular momentum involves specifying an inertial reference frame and an origin point that is at rest in this frame. The angular momentum is then defined as $\mathbf{L} = \sum\mathbf{r}\times\mathbf{p}$, where position $\mathbf{r}$ is measured relative to the chosen origin and momentum $\mathbf{p}$ is measured in the chosen inertial frame.
This angular momentum is conserved in the sense that its value at one time equals its value at another time, using the same inertial frame and origin. Its value will generally be different, but still conserved, with another choice of inertial frame and/or origin.
Now, your scenario where "the angular momentum of either body [say body 2] is taken about the other [say body 1]" is a different definition.
First interpretation
Assume we still use an inertial frame to measure momentum $\mathbf{p}$, but we use the position of body 1 at each instant of time as the origin point for computing angular momentum at that time. This origin is not at rest (in any inertial frame). Thus, the resulting angular momentum is generally not constant over time, i.e., not conserved.
If $\mathbf{r}_1$ is the time-dependent position of body 1 relative to some point $O$ at rest in the chosen inertial frame, then compared to the standard angular momentum formula $\sum\mathbf{r}\times\mathbf{p}$ about $O$, each position in the formula is replaced by $\mathbf{r} \to \mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_1$ (position relative to body 1). So our nonstandard angular momentum differs from the standard angular momentum about the point $O$ by the amount $\sum(-\mathbf{r}_1\times\mathbf{p}) = -\mathbf{r}_1\times\mathbf{P}$, where $\mathbf{P}$ is the (conserved) total momentum of the system. There is no reason that body 1's velocity $\dot{\mathbf{r}}_1$ ($= \mathbf{p}_1/m_1$) must be parallel to $\mathbf{P}$, hence the nonconservation.
The exception is if $\mathbf{P} = \mathbf{0}$, i.e., if we use the barycenter frame. In this case, we match the standard angular momentum and obtain conservation.
Second interpretation
Assume we use a noninertial frame (nonrotating, for simplicity) defined to keep our origin point, body 1, apparently at rest. This changes the meaning of momentum $\mathbf{p}$. This is the frame used for the traditional one-body reduction of the two-body problem.
So we have yet another angular momentum. To evaluate it, first note that the standard angular momentum in the barycenter frame is $\mathbf{L} = \mathbf{r}_1\times\mathbf{p}_1 + \mathbf{r}_2\times\mathbf{p}_2 = (\mathbf{r}_2 - \mathbf{r}_1) \times\mathbf{p}_2$, because $\mathbf{p}_1 + \mathbf{p}_2 = \mathbf{0}$.
Now, we need to evaluate the apparent position and momentum of body 2 in the noninertial frame (only body 2 contributes to the apparent angular momentum in this frame). The velocity of body 2 relative to body 1 is $\dot{\mathbf{r}}_2 - \dot{\mathbf{r}}_1 = \mathbf{p}_2/m_2 - \mathbf{p}_1/m_1 = \mathbf{p}_2(1/m_1 + 1/m_2) = \mathbf{p}_2/\mu$, where $\mu$ is the reduced mass.
Thus the apparent angular momentum in the noninertial frame is
$(\mathbf{r}_2 - \mathbf{r}_1) \times m_2\mathbf{p}_2/\mu$. This is a fixed multiple of the standard angular momentum $\mathbf{L}$ and so is conserved. In fact, the traditional one-body reduction goes a step further and, in addition to using this noninertial frame, assigns $\mu$ (instead of $m_2$) as the fictitious mass of body 2. If this is done, then the angular momentum matches exactly.
Another way to see that angular momentum is conserved in the noninertial frame is that, since the frame acceleration is $\ddot{\mathbf{r}}_1$, body 2 experiences the fictitious force $-m_2\ddot{\mathbf{r}}_1$. This is parallel to the physical force on body 1 causing the acceleration $\ddot{\mathbf{r}}_1$, which in turn is central, i.e., parallel to $(\mathbf{r}_2 - \mathbf{r}_1)$. Thus, the fictitious torque on body 2 is zero.

Can you explain where you got the -r_1 cross p term in the "first interpretation" paragraph?

@AeroMain27 Explanation added.
